# Postponing a bris for parents or grandparents

Tags: brit-milah

Is one allowed to postpone a bris(bzmano) for the afternoon if ones parents or grandparents cannot make the bris for the morning.  What is more important ,zrizim makdimin ( to peform the mitzvah as soon as one possibly can) or kibud av veim ( honoring ones parents). ?

Comment: Parents of the Nimol or of his father?

Comment: the question is for both,thats why  I wrote parents and grandparents

Comment: I didn't know if you meant "parents and grandparents [of the father of the Nimol]" thereby excluding the parents of the Nimol.

Comment: What is the hefsed if afternoon is also Bizmano?

Comment: whats the hefsed?! the gemara says zrizin makdimin mitzvos and many hold its a chov (obligation).

Comment: So you can ask about make a brit after vasikin because the grand father pray 1 hour after nets

Comment: Not sure if you got the depth of double aa's point but if the father of the nimol isn't there, who's having this child circumcised and why?

Comment: `וכל היום כשר למילה אלא שזריזין מקדימי' למצוה ומלין מיד בבקר ואפי' מילה שלא בזמנה אינה אלא ביום:` But maybe that when you can add other mitsvot e. g.  Kibud Av or to cause a bit of nachas ruach to some family members this is not less mitsva than zrizim makdimim.  I am not  sure  so tis is not an answer.

Comment: i understood doubleaa point,my question is for both because there are shittos who hold that the milah must be done even of father cannot be there

Comment: @user6591 he could send a sliach perhaps, but then we'd have to contend with mitzva bo yoser mibeshlucho

Comment: @Double for sure. But addressing that is a bigger (more explicit) issue.

Comment: "there are shittos who hold that the milah must be done even of father cannot be there"  Even if father will come the 8th day?

Answer (score 1):

See  Bet Chadash Yore Dea siman  262:

> אלא שזריזין מקדימין למצוה מיד בבוקר דהיינו משתנץ החמה וזהו שלא כתב שזריזין מקדימין למצוה מיד בעלות השחר אלא בבוקר שהוא לאחר עמוד השחר משתנץ החמה וכמ"ש בתחילה זמן המילה ביום שמנה דהיינו בבוקר שנקרא יום בלשון בני אדם כשתנץ החמה
>
> But  Zrizim makdimim concerns Henets Hachama.

If the father want to make it at Henets the question is relevant but not for a discussion concerning 10:00 or 13:00

The source is in Gemara  Pesachim 4a:

> דכתיב (ויקרא יב) וביום השמיני ימול בשר ערלתו ותניא כל היום כולו כשר למילה אלא שזריזין מקדימים למצות שנאמר (בראשית כב) וישכם אברהם בבקר ‏

Rashi:

> וישכם אברהם בבקר שלא המתין עד הנץ החמה ומכל מקום בלילה לא הקדים:‏

In Hava Amina we see that Zrizim concerns the beginning of the day  only,  and in maskana the beginning of the time only. Concerning Avraham the beginning of the right time to g there  is not a question of makdimim for a simple question of hours  only.
`to peform the mitzvah as soon as one possibly can` seems not to be a the exact case of zrizim makdimim.

If you see the Tosfot  you can see how he try to explain in  Hava Amina that they can go out at night.  But in Maskana morning is obviously the first right time to go out.

The question is relevant in a case in which the father is really makpid to make mitsvot of day at Henets. And obviously the shikul is for the mitsva itself not for a combination of additional mitsvot together.